# Where to buy ubuntu for android phone dock?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

Where can I buy the Ubuntu for Android phone dock and phone with Ubuntu on?

Like this one: http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android

Comment: It is not available yet

Answer (score 1):

This product hasn't been finished yet to my knowledge. It's deceptive that they don't tell you this on the web-page.

Most of the focus right now is on finishing and shipping Ubuntu Touch. Ubuntu for Android is quite different from it, and is on hold right now I think.

"Ubuntu for Android, currently under development..." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_for_Android

Answer (score 0):

The '*dock*' is hardware, which may be available for your phone.

[generic USB dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1arTK.gif)

---

Otherwise (as others have said), there is not a current / stable '*ubuntu for android*' build for you to use.

***Be patient ..***